# Macro inputs from text file to draw nodes at x,y where x,y values are read from the file

Tags: macros, draw

I am drawing boxes using a macro like

```
\newcommand{\drawbox}[2]{
\node[box, fill=green] at (#1,#2){};
}
```

where I specify the arguments `#1` and `#2` (that correspond to x,y values) when calling the macro.

Now I need to draw multiple boxes where values of the arguments `#1` and `#2` are in a column in a text file. I probably need a for loop but how can I read each line of the text file to get arguments `#1` and `#2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution with `datatool`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{coordinates}{points.csv}

\newcommand{\drawbox}[2]{
  \node[draw, fill=green] at (#1,#2){};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\DTLforeach*{coordinates}{\x=x,\y=y}{%
  \drawbox{\x}{\y}
}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

where `points.csv` has the structure

```
x,y
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

**EDIT**

A slightly modified version of your code, just to showcase the things you can do with this

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb{coordinates}{points.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={
      draw,
      fill = green,
      minimum width = 2cm,
      minimum height = 1cm,
      label = center:#1,
      opacity = 0.2
    }
  ]
\DTLforeach*{coordinates}{\x=x,\y=y,\text=text}{%
  \node[box=\text] (\theDTLrowi) at (\x, \y){};
}

\draw[red, ->] (1) to (2);
\draw[red, ->] (2) to (3);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case the input file is

```
x,y,text
1,2,foo
3,4,var
5,6,baz
```